# How to compile a makefile on OSX 10.8 with no Terminal experience?

Tags: macos, compilation, makefile, terminal, puredata

I've tried searching on this and everything seems to assume more knowledge on the subject than I have. I've downloaded this PureData external: https://github.com/badgeek/fux_videoglitch , and I think I need to compile the makefile, but I don't know how to do this. There doesn't seem to be a readMe with any instructions, and I can't seem to figure it out from any search hits. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you'll need to install either Xcode or Make. There's another stack question that relates the process for installing make in OSX [install make command without already having make (mac os 10.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556444/install-make-command-without-already-having-make-mac-os-10-5)

At which point you'll simply put in to terminal:

```
make targetfile
```

http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/ has some great background on how this works. Make is simply for compiling big multifile programs.

IIRC Pure Data is kind of tricky to compile in the first place, so you'll want to keep instructions for compilation handy - the Pure Data mailing list often has users confused by this process.